# How to create conditional unique constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Having a table:`Table1` in which a column `Code` accepts nullables values how can we insure that values are unique for non nullable values except for codes that start with `'A'` which can be duplicated maximum twice?

**Table1**

```
Id |  Code
---------- 
1  |  NULL   --[ok]
2  |  A123   --[ok]
3  |  A123   --[ok]
4  |  B100   --[ok] 
5  |  C200   --[ok]
6  |  B100   --[not ok already used]
7  |  NULL   --[ok]
```

What i have tried is creating an indexed view, the solution work fine for `NULL` values but not for the second case i mentioned (skipped actualy)

```
Create view v_Table_unq with schemabinding as( 
         select code from 
         dbo.Table1 
         where code is not null and code not like 'A%'
)
go
create unique clustered index unq_code on v_Table_unq(code)
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Table Creation

```
CREATE TABLE CheckConstraint
(
  Name VARCHAR(50),
)
GO
```

---

### Function Creation

```
create FUNCTION CheckDuplicateWithA() RETURNS INT AS BEGIN

  DECLARE @ret INT  =0 ;
  SELECT @ret = IsNull(COUNT(Name), 0) FROM CheckConstraint WHERE Name like '[A]%' group by Name having COUNT(name) >= 1;
  RETURN IsNUll(@ret, 0);
END;

GO

create FUNCTION CheckDuplicateOtherThenA() RETURNS INT AS BEGIN

  DECLARE @ret INT  =0 ;
  SELECT @ret = IsNull(COUNT(Name), 0) FROM CheckConstraint WHERE Name not like '[A]%' group by Name having COUNT(name) >= 1;
  RETURN IsNUll(@ret, 0);
END;
```

---

```
GO
```

### Constraints

```
alter TABLE CheckConstraint
  add CONSTRAINT CheckDuplicateContraintWithA CHECK (NOT (dbo.CheckDuplicateWithA() > 2));
go

alter TABLE CheckConstraint
  add CONSTRAINT CheckDuplicateConmstraintOtherThenA CHECK (NOT (dbo.CheckDuplicateOtherThenA() > 1));
go
```

---

### Result Set

```
insert into CheckConstraint(Name)Values('b')  -- Passed
insert into CheckConstraint(Name)Values('b')  -- Failed

insert into CheckConstraint(Name)Values('a')  -- Passed
insert into CheckConstraint(Name)Values('a')  -- Passed
insert into CheckConstraint(Name)Values('a')  -- Failed
```

Comment: What about the performance for each check it will do full table scan or in best case full index scan twice? This will kill the performance.Trigger or having a single sp to make the changes to the table is best option.

Comment: Index will search the specific page.

Comment: You are not providing any parameters so the whole index will be scanned.You have to pass the current insertion value to the functions to make sure that it is working on just a single row.It wont search a specific page.for first function it will serach anything which starts with A and for other one everything which starrts with B and till the end of the index and will search for null as well.

Comment: It's like a parameter. While searching for a existence/duplicate record index will go to specific page. Make sure the Non Clustered index exists

Comment: You have not specified the parameter.when the constraint will be checked the function will be called and that will search full table's data.Try this with say 10000 records and you will see what I am talking about..

Comment: You are right.
When function will perform search, it will go through complete table. **BUT** This is the case,  when case index is missing.

In case of Non Clustered Index - I am right.

Comment: In case of non clustered index it will do full index scan and not a seek.As the table size will grow size of non clustered index will grow.Thus it  will scan a bigger index.Try to pass the column name as input parameter to these functions and use that value in where clause so that you use max two rows of non clustered index instead of full index scan.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want a unique contraint? Why cant add this logic in the proc which inserts the data in the table?If you do not have a single point of insertion/updation etc?Why cant put it in instead of or after trigger?That would be much better as you can handle it well and could return proper errror messages.This will have less overhead than having a index view which will add to overhead.If you need unique constraint for the records which doesnt start with 'A' then you can have a persisted column and have a unique constraint on that.

Off course you will have overhead of having persisted computed column with index..But if you just need unique contsraint you can use that.For values which starts with 'A' this could be a null value.

Comment: this is similar to the code i posted which does not work as expected

Comment: This misses the part that values that start with 'A' can only be duplicated a maximum of twice.

Comment: I did not read the maximum twice part...I guess trigger is right choice here

Comment: Why would you want a unique contraint? Why cant add this logic in the proc which inserts the data in the table?If you do not have a single point of insertion/updation etc?Why cant put it in instead of or after trigger?That would be much better as you can handle it well and could return proper errror messages.This will have less overhead than having a index view which will add to overhead.If you need unique constraint for the records which doesnt start with 'A' then you can have a persisted column and have a unique constraint on that.

Comment: Off course you will have overhead of having persisted computed column with index..But if you just need unique contsraint you can use that.For values which starts with 'A' this could be a null value.